# Split the JSON element into individual elements and add any new elements to the options of a drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grep

I am a beginner at working with JSON and have not used it much, how do I split the genre for a tv show into individual genres and add any new genres to the options of the drop down? I want to split the genres that have a '|' and then add them to the 2nd drop-down select as options. How do I also set "Comedy" as the default option? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
 $(function () {
            $("#chooseByGenre").click(function () {
                var text = $("#yourGenre").val();
                text = text.replace(/\|, " ");
                var edg = text.split("");
                $("#genreSelection").html("");

                for (i = 0; i < edg.length; i++) {
                    if (edg[i] < "a" || edg[i] > "z") {
                        $("#genreSelection").append("<br />");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#genreSelection").append('<img src="sign' + edg[i] + '.g" />');
                    }

                }
            });
```

code for default option:

```
var JSON_Response;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON('Show.json', function (data) {
        JSON_Response = data;  


        var mySelect = document.getElementById("selShow");

        for (i = 0; i < JSON_Response.shows.length; i++) {
            var myOption = document.createElement("option");
            myOption.text = JSON_Response.shows[i].Title;
            myOption.value = i;
            try {

                mySelect.add(myOption, mySelect.options[null]);
            }
            catch (e) {
                mySelect.add(myOption, null);
            }
        } //end for 



var mySelect2 = document.getElementById("selGenre");

        for (i = 0; i < JSON_Response.shows.length; i++) {
            var myOption2 = document.createElement("option");
            myOption2.text = JSON_Response.shows[i].Genre;
            myOption2.value = i;
            try {

                mySelect2.add(myOption2, mySelect2.options[null]);
            }
            catch (e) {
                mySelect2.add(myOption, null);
            }
        } //end for 

    }); //end getJSON
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you can try like this? (haven't tested yet):

```
   ...
   try {
       if ( myOption2.text == 'comedy') {
          myOption2.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
       }
       mySelect2.add(myOption2, mySelect2.options[null]);
    }
    ...
```